# How to set the weights of an expert on a binary decision?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization

Suppose that we have $n$ experts, each will give us a prediction $X_i$ on whether a binary event $E\in\{0,1\}$ will take place.

Suppose also that we know the probability that each of them will be correct (say, expert $i$ is correct w.p. $p_i\in(0,1/2)$), and that their predictions are independent of each other.

Our goal is to decide on *weights* $w_i,\ldots,w_n$ such that the prediction of the weighted majority is correct with the highest possible probability.

Namely, consider the event $E'=(\sum_i X_i\cdot w_i \ge 1/2\cdot \sum_i w_i)$, and we'd like to maximize the probability that $E=E'$.

> **What is the best way to set the weights if $w_i$ can only be defined using $P_i$?**

> **What is the best way to set the weights if all weights can be based on all $P_i$'s?**

I'm more interested in the first question :).

Comment: Have a look at the pretty extensive literature on ensemble learning.

Comment: @Aruralreader. Thanks for the pointer, but I'm not sure there's any `learning' here as I have a single binary events and the $p_i$'s are known in advance?

Comment: It sounds like you have a set of naive Bayes classifiers, or maybe something more sophisticated than that, and you want to figure out, based on data, how to weight the decision of each expert.

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting a weighted experts problem as presented and explained [(1)](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall13/cos521/lecnotes/lec8.pdf) & [(2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lz8xCaDjloY)
Basically you choose probability based on weights variable, like for expert $i$ probability of being correct $p_i = {w_i\over \sum_i w_i}$
Initial weights can be taken equally as 1.
Then you have loss $m_i= 1$ if correctly predicted $x_i$, $0$ otherwise (basically $0 - \vert X - x_i \vert$) where $X$ is the realized event. Compute the expected (average) loss
$ E =$ **m**$\cdot$**p**
Repeat $t$ times and update weights assigned using factor $ \eta \in (0,1)$
$ w_{i}^{t+1} = (1-\eta m_{i}^{t})w_{i}^{t}$
$ \eta$ is like learning step & is a random value to be chosen, you can start with a value $ \ge 0.7$ & then in subsequent iterations choose a lower value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this seems to assume that there are multiple iterations of the process, while I am asssuming that the $p_i$'s are known, but there's a single-shot. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MA if you want to consider weights as $w$ same as $p$, $\sum_i w_i= 1$ & these are independent, then one way is to maximize $\prod w$. You can take the log of that to linearize. If $p$ are known & different from weights then maximize $\prod Pw$